# Admin role isn't being assigned in my seed data when I have roles in  my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my seed file I am trying to create 3 users, 1 `admin` and 2 `default` users but it keeps assigning all 3 users to the `default` role before creation. Here is my code:

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :user_prices
  has_many :products, :through => :user_prices
  validates_presence_of :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  validates_format_of :username, :with => /\A[a-z0-9]{5,20}\z/i
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email

  before_create :setup_default_role_for_new_users

  ROLES = %w[admin default]

  private
  def setup_default_role_for_new_users
    if self.role.blank?
      self.role = "default"
    end
  end
end
```

**Seed.rb**

```
puts 'Loading seed data now....'
user1 = User.create(:email => 'admin@email.com', :role => 'admin')
user2 = User.create(:email => 'user1@email.com')
user3 = User.create(:email => 'user2@email.com')
puts 'Users added'
```

I know user2 and user3 will have the `default` role but user1 should be `admin`. How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since :role isnt in your accessible attributes, its protected from mass assignment, which is what you are doing in your seed file.

so in order to set role, you can use something like this

> user1 = User.create(:email => 'admin@email.com')
>   user1.update_attribute(:role, 'admin')

Answer (score 1):

Use `if` not `unless`:

```
def setup_default_role_for_new_users
  if self.role.blank? # if not unless
    self.role = "default"
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo from trying some things. Yeah I tried it again and it still gives the `default` role to all users.

Comment: Well, then it must be that you did not add it to attr_accessible